# METEOR - Passing data from between parent template to a child template

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, meteor

I'm trying to create a two-way table with two collections in meteorJS where i could pass the name of one collection from the parent template to child template.

Item is the x-axis and Item2 is the y-axis.

My Collections :

```
db.Item.insert({
    "name" : "hello",
    "param1" : "ok",
    "param2" : "ok",
    "parma3" : "na"
});

db.Item.insert({
    "name" : "bonjour",
    "param1" : "na",
    "param2" : "ok",
    "parma3" : "ok"
});

db.Item2.insert({
    "id" : "01",
    "nameIt2" : "nameS"
});

db.Item2.insert({
    "id" : "02",
    "nameIt2" : "name"
});
```

My Code HTML :

```
 <template name="home">
   <table class="table maintable">
      <!--Entête du tableau (première ligne)-->
      <tbody>
        {{#each event}}
          {{> eventItem}}
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
   </table>
</template>


<template name="eventItem">
  <tr>
    {{#each event2}}
      {{> eventItem2}}
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
</template>

<template name="eventItem2">
  <td>
    {{nameItem}}
  </td>
</template>
```

My JS code :

```
Template.home.helpers({
event() {
    return Item.find();
  },
});

Template.eventItem.helpers({
event2() {
    return Item2.find();
  },
});

Template.eventItem.helpers({
event2() {
    return Item2.find();
  },
});

Template.eventItem2.helpers({
nameItem() {
    return **Name field of my collection Item**
  },
});
```

Is there a way to pass the **Name of each Item** from the parent template *eventItem* to child template *eventItem2* ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could use [`Template.parentData`](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-parentData) to access the data of parent template:

```
Template.eventItem2.helpers({
  nameItem() {
    return Template.parentData().name;
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set value in you child template in order pass the data.

You can pass data like this:

```
<template name="home">
   <table class="table maintable">
      <!--Entête du tableau (première ligne)-->
      <tbody>
        {{#each event}}
          {{> eventItem childEvent=this}}
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
   </table>
</template>


<template name="eventItem">
  <tr>
    {{#each childEvent}}
      {{> eventItem2 nameItem=this}}
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
</template>

<template name="eventItem2">
  <td>
    {{nameItem}}
  </td>
</template>
```

*Note: This represent the current value in #each